# Error, some other host already uses address IPADDRESS

Tags: networking, centos

I have the following scenario on my Centos 6.2 server:

`eth0` : has IP `192.168.50.10`

`eth0:5` : has IP `10.0.0.1`

When I boot the system, everything is up and working. When I run: `ifdown eth0:5` and after `ifup eth0:5`, I get this error: `Error, some other host already uses address 10.0.0.1`. After I run `ifdown eth0:5`, I can ping the `10.0.0.1` host, but I cannot connect to it via `ssh` (from the same host). Before of `ifdown` command, I can ping the `10.0.0.1` and connect to it via `ssh` (from the same host). If I type `service network restart`, everything is ok again.

**Question**: Can anyone infer why that behavior?

N.B. I don't have the `NetworkManager` installed, and I don't have another host with this IP on the LAN (`10.0.0.1`).

EDIT:

The result of `$arp -na` command:

> ? (82.208.147.126) at 00:07:0e:5c:99:26 [ether] on eth0

Comment: add the output of 'arp -na'. Chances are that another host on the same network has the same address. In this case, change it.

Comment: @Aki you are right I think, because when I ping the `10.0.0.1` after the `ifdown` run, the time is much grater than the previous one. Anyway, I changed the gateway of my server to another workable one, and the problem was not anymore. I think there were some routing conflicts. Thanks.

Comment: RHEL-like distros have arping in their networking scripts which checks if the IP is already used in LAN. This explains the error.

Answer (score 1):

There IS another entity using that IP.

You could use `nmap -O 10.0.0.1` to find out what it is.

Comment: Is there a way to force to use already used IP address? Just to take it away from the interface that is using it? I have IPKVM in my nic1 and I wanted to disable it from inside Linux somehow so IPKVM wouldn't hang on public it. When the system is down or restarted the IPKVM would start working again as it's IP address is not overwritten by Linux? Or there maybe other ways?

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev so that IP is in use on a different interface on your server? What is your `nmap`-output? What does `arp -an|grep "10.0.0.1"` show? You should not force an IP unless you really know what you are doing.

Comment: Those commands show the presence of interfaces on current IP. Like I mentioned above, I just would like to try to shutdown RMM (IPKMV) that is set via server bios as a static IP address. If I could do that than I would stop IPKVM hanging in public before I restart my system or enter a command. Where could I read about taking an IP address. Or how could I try to do it? I actually thought it wasn't possible?

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev the MAC-Prefix **00-07-0E** is registered to **Cisco Systems Inc.**. This looks like a cisco-device - possibly a router, whose mac-address you see through eth0 (not ON eth0). Talk to your network-guys and get a free IP for your server.